# Firebase Functions GET http://localhost:5001/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to firebase, and trying to host my Angular 6 + node.js + express app at firebase, using firebase functions.

I have checked all paths to exist.
This is the code in my functions/index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/myProject')));


// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../dist/myProject/index.html'));
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

The way I understand, my site should be visible at the address firebase has supplied me with:

> http://localhost:5001/myproject-1529850544497/us-central1/app

When typing in this address in my browser, this is the error i'm getting (x12 times):

```
GET http://localhost:5001/styles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I make it so the index.html is returned properly?

Comment: it's complaining you don't aave a route for /runtime.js.  Where is that file?

Comment: ok, I found some scripts I pasted in index.html that are pointing to some srcs. I took those scripts when started the firebase initialization with the instructions on their website. Eventually I did the initialization using the cli - firebase init hosting. now I removed those scripts and the screen is white + no errors. cant see the app-root output

Comment: something in your project is looking for styles.js and runtime.js to be mounted at '/'.   The only mount you have (app.use) is publishing the contents of dist/myProject at '/'.  The default route is returning index.html.

Can you show us what's in dist/myProject?  your index.html would be helpful too.